# Why doesn't git provide a clone parameter to specify a commitId?

Tags: git, github

I want git to clone the specified commitId of a branch, knowing the repository address, branch, and commitId.I also want to use `--branch="master" --single-branch --depth=1` to optimize the clone speed.

I googled it and found that most of the answers are to clone the full commit history for that branch (which is too large for my project) and then git checkout commitId.

I'm actually more curious as to why the git doesn't provide a parameter like this. `git clone --commitId="xxxxxxxxx" --branch="master" --single-branch --depth=1` 
Thanks!

Comment: if you want to know why ask the git developers. how should we know? what about the shallow options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-b` or `--branch` option to `git clone` is not necessarily a branch name.  For instance:

```
git clone -b v2.29.2 https://github.com/git/git.git --depth 1
```

works fine.

Because of the above, `git clone -b <hash-id>` (with or without `--depth`) *should* also be allowed—but it isn't:

```
Cloning into 'git'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 898f80736c75878acc02dc55672317fcc0e0a5a6 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 898f80736c75878acc02dc55672317fcc0e0a5a6 not found in upstream origin
```

There are multiple separate reasons it's not allowed, but the key one right now—which is that direct access to a commit hash ID might violate some sort of theoretical security options—is being dismantled to allow partial clones to fetch objects by ID directly.  Once that's sufficiently commonly out of the way, `git clone` should learn to do the above.

Until then, clone by tag (which is allowed).

Note that the:

> ```
> --single-branch
> ```

flag is already implied by `--depth 1`: shallow clones are by default single-branch clones.  Further, when `-b` specifies a tag (or, in the theoretical future, a raw commit hash), the resulting clone has *no* branches and is in detached HEAD state, so there is no point in specifying a branch name.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I guess I'll have to go with the clone all history and checkout now.

By the way, what is the approximate security option you mentioned?

Comment: The general idea behind prohibiting direct access by hash ID was that some objects (commits and their files) could be hidden by being unreachable from a branch or tag name. A `git clone` would then not copy these objects either. But this was never developed into any sort of serious security model, and the new promisor pack / download-loader model requires direct access by hash ID, so the old configuration flag, "allow any hash ID in want", is nonfunctional in the newer protocols which now just automatically allow it.

Comment: Note also that if you can get whoever owns the source repository to *tag* the commit you want, you can clone-by-tag today (as illustrated in the answer above).

Comment: got it ! Thanks again